# How to get fixed m from different pairs of n, e and c in RSA？

Tags: rsa, public-key

In RSA cryptosystem, if I have two (or more) pairs of public key and also the corresponding ciphertexts, can I get the fixed message from them? I cannot think up any good idea for now.

Comment: You might want to explain more about what you're asking.  Are you asking about a situation where you have two different ciphertexts (encrypted by two different public keys), and which happen to encrypt the same plaintext $m$?  If so, well, you can't recover the common plaintext message from that.

Comment: @poncho Yes, this is what I wanted to say. If I cannot recover the message from two pubkeys, then how about k pubkeys?(where k > max{e_i}.) Maybe it's like Hastad Attack based on Chinese Remainder Theorem and Coppersmith's attack?(I saw it before on the Wikipedia) Sorry I do not really understand it.